# R + ggplot, colors not showing correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to create this map with some points one it, but the colors that I selected are not showing up. Instead I am getting like default colors and I am struggling to find why and fix. Can anyone help, please?

Thank you!

city_data.uni

```
     city latitude longitude reps acesso city_color
1         Coari-AM -4.09412  -63.1441    1     NA    #FCB03C
2      Alenquer-PA -1.94623  -54.7384   14     NA    #F8C110
16 Monte Alegre-PA -1.99768  -54.0724    6     NA    #09459D
22       Placas-PA -3.86813  -54.2124    7     NA    #76B729
29     Santarem-PA -2.43849  -54.6996   35     NA    #9BA851
```

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = brazil_map, fill = "#cfd8dc", color = "gray10") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-74, -43), ylim = c(-12, 7), expand = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data = city_data.uni, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, size = reps, color = city_color), alpha = 6/10, show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = city_data.uni$city_color, labels = city_data.uni$city, name = "Distribuição de Projetos") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3,8)) +
  guides(size="none") +
  #labs(title = "Distribuição de projetos") +
  #theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=5), legend.title = element_text(size=5)) +
  #theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftaDp.jpg

Tried to replace scale_color_manual by scale_fill_manual, but it didn't work, I got legends with all gray colors on it.

Comment: I think you want `scale_color_identity` if you want ggplot to take a variable as a literal color assignment.